# Why does angular add ng-version attribute to the app-root html tag

Tags: html, angular, security

Today, I noticed that Angular adds its version information in the app-root as following:

```
<app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="5.2.0">
```

And even when I build in the production environment, it seems to be present. I don't know what's the main goal for adding that information there ? Isn't it a security issue to show the angular version publicly ? Thanks

Comment: Security by obscurity **may** prevent from google dorks attackers. Anyway, I can't seem to find a use for this attribute expect consuming some tiny bytes in the html file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular uses this attribute to tag the element that was used to bootstrap the application.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/a4de214e2be5048f1261d043cc467a5ecaa5c909

Hiding it would only be security by obscurity which is not security.

Comment: Thanks I am now convainced. And I also learned that I can get many answers from github commit messages that are well formatted :D (of course)

Comment: Saying hiding version numbers is security through obscurity is simply not true as @lordmairtis points out. Hiding version numbers of software used is a security best practice you'll find in any hardening guide.

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question, but still relevant and the accepted answer could be misleading.
[According to Miško Hevery](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16283): "This is there intentionally, so that tools such an augury, can detect that it is an angular page and can provide useful UI."

It is not a security issue in itself, but hiding it isn't "security by obscurity" either, as that would mean that's all the security measures you take.
In fact [using obscurity](https://danielmiessler.com/study/security-by-obscurity/) is a good practice as it [makes information gathering (recon) harder](https://www.dhs.gov/science-and-technology/csd-mtd) for the attacker, but one must never rely on this alone.

Comment: Cool, very interesting, I didn’t found the github issue when I was searching back at that time. I think the objective behind it (augury) is so dumb because DOM have nothing to do with that kind of stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Go to your root component and add this [piece of code](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16283#issuecomment-347800960) to remove `ng-version` attribute:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[data-app]',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute("ng-version");
    }
}
```